# Concatenate many rows with same Name in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to get the output I need with this, can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**Output should be**

```
1 | Adam | Math, Science
2 | Tony | Math
3 | Erica | English, History
```

**But I keep resulting with**

```
1 | Adam | Math, Science, English, History
2 | Tony | Math, Science, English, History
3 | Erica | Math, Science, English, History
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE T
(
    ID INT,
    WM VARCHAR(50),
    Class VARCHAR(50),
    Prof VARCHAR(50),
)

INSERT INTO T (ID, WM, Class, Prof)
VALUES
    (NULL, 'Adam', 'Math', 'Sam'),
    (1, 'Adam', 'Science', 'Marc'),
    (2, 'Tony','Math', 'Sam'),
    (3, 'Erica','English', 'P'),
    (3, 'Erica','History', 'P')


SELECT *, STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Class
            FROM T
            WHERE T.WM = T.WM
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT WM
    FROM T
) T
```

Please leave a reason why, if leaving negative results

Comment: I don't think my WHERE clause is working at all.

Comment: Probably. You should give the inner table a different alias.

Comment: @Sam If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as answer

Answer (score 4):

The issue is in `where T.WM = T.WM` statement

```
SELECT *, STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Class
            FROM T as T2
            WHERE T.WM = T2.WM
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT WM
    FROM T
) T
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CTE`:

```
with cte as (
    select *, max(id) over (PARTITION by wm) NewId
    from t
)
SELECT NewId, WM, STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Class
            FROM cte
            WHERE C.WM = WM
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM cte c
group by NewId, WM
```

Check [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6fe30/4)